# OpenCv Core.add error

Tags: android, opencv

I've a problem with this metod of opencv library...

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image , image , Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

        Mat prob_fgd = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U,
                new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD));

        try {
            Imgproc.grabCut(image, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, 3, 0);
        } catch (Exception w) {
            System.out.println(w.getMessage());
        }

        Core.compare(firstMask, prob_fgd, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ);
        foreground = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255,
                255));

        image.copyTo(foreground, firstMask);

        Imgproc.resize(background, background, image.size());

        mask = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(100, 255,
                100));

        foreground = overlay_colored_roi(foreground, new Scalar(100, 255, 100));

        Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        mask.copyTo(ref);

        vals = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0.0));

        background.copyTo(dst);

        background.setTo(vals, mask);
```

until here the code works.
here it stop.

log say that input element of core.add must have the same size but background.size()) foreground.size()) dst.size()) mask.size()) are equals.

```
Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They also must have the same number of channels.Since in the code background initialization is not shown I'm assuming that must be the problem.Secondly try normal addition function that is without the mask and check the output.If the problem still persists post the full code.Hope this helps.